# noun + verb + comparative degree + than I thought

Tags: comparative-constructions

What are the Japanese constructions to express the following English formula?

**noun + verb + comparative degree + than I thought**

E.g.

*Today is colder than I thought.*

*This works better than I thought.*

Is it possible to say?

今日は思ったより寒いです。

これは思ったより上手く行く。

Comment: Both of your sentences sound fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got the good idea, but you just have to be careful to not make logical or verb tense mistakes.

For example,

> 思ったより上手く行く

Should probably be

> 思ったより上手くいった。-> It went better than expected.
>   思ったより上手くいっている。-> It is going better than expected.

Right now you are expressing present/future tense, which doesn't fit well with your thought in the past.  You could say it like that though.

> 思っているより上手くいくでしょ。-> It's probably gonna go better than your are thinking.

As for talking about things like the weather, you might want to use words like 予定 instead of 思い. There is a certain nuance between what you think and what is planned.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with 「思ったよりうまくいく」.